# Print int i from for loop into a separate method from the for loop

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi is there any way to get the int i from the for loop in NFTLP to print out in NFTLPAddBox method so it says which box is added in which truck, e.g box 1 added at truck 0, box 2 added at truck 0 box 3 added at truck 1 etc.

```
    public void NFTLP() {
    trucks.clear();
    trucks.add(new Truck());
    System.out.println("");
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.setStackWidth(boxes[0].getWidth());
    trucks.get(0).addStack(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        NFTLPAddBox(boxes[i],
                trucks.get(trucks.size() - 1).getStack().get(trucks.get(trucks.size() - 1).getStack().size() - 1),
                trucks.get(trucks.size() - 1));
    }
    System.out.println("Trucks used: " + trucks.size());
    System.out.println("Stacks used: " + Truck.stacks);
}

public void NFTLPAddBox(Box b, Stack s, Truck t) {
    if (t.getBoxNum() < Truck.BOX_LIMIT) {
        if (b.getWidth() <= s.getStackWidth() && s.getStackHeight() + b.getHeight() <= Truck.TRUCK_HEIGHT) {
            s.addBox(b);
            t.boxNum++;
            System.out.println("Box added at Truck: " + trucks.indexOf(t) + " Stack: "
                    + Integer.toString(trucks.get(trucks.indexOf(t)).getStack().size() - 1));
        } else {
            Stack s2 = new Stack();
            if (t.getCurrentStackWidth() + b.getWidth() <= Truck.TRUCK_WIDTH
                    && b.getHeight() <= Truck.TRUCK_HEIGHT) {
                s2.addBox(b);
                t.addStack(s);
                t.boxNum++;
                System.out.println("Box added at Truck: " + trucks.indexOf(t) + " Stack: "
                        + Integer.toString(trucks.get(trucks.indexOf(t)).getStack().size() - 1));
            }
```

Comment: Pass `i` as a parameter to `NFTLPAddBox`?

Comment: ahh why did I not think of that, thanks very much.